# variable acting like pointer when its not Java

Tags: java

I hava java App which simulates the game of "craps".
On the application I have a method rollDice() which returns the sum of two random numbers. I also have a button which when its click it calls a method called botonjugar_presionado( ActionEvent event).

On the method botonjugar_perionado the fallowing suppose to happen

1. The method rollDice() is called and its return value store on sumOfDice
2. A switch structure uses the value of sumOfDice to do diferent operations depending on sumOfDice value

When I click the button my application is not working like it suppose to. So when trying to debug I use a  System.out.println(Integer.toString(sumOfDice)); to see what is the number of sumOfDice. But it seems like its calling rollDice() for a second time ? Any idea why this is happening.The code is show below.
Thank you in advance !

```
//import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class HelloWorld extends JFrame
{
private JButton botonjugar;

private JLabel texto1;
private JLabel texto2;
private JLabel texto3;
private JLabel texto4;
private JLabel textoinfo;

private static JTextField caja1;
private static JTextField caja2;
private static JTextField caja3;
private JTextField caja4;

// create random number generator for use in method rollDice
private static final Random randomNumbers = new Random();

// enumeration with constants that represent the game status
//private enum Status { CONTINUE, WON, LOST };

// constants that represent common rolls of the dice
private static final int SNAKE_EYES = 2;
private static final int TREY = 3;
private static final int SEVEN = 7;
private static final int YO_LEVEN = 11;
private static final int BOX_CARS = 12;

public boolean chequear = true;
 public int myPoint;
public int sumOfDice;
public String gameStatus;
public String prueba = "";

public HelloWorld()
{
 qui();
}

public void qui()
{
 gameStatus="";
 myPoint =0;
 // get content pane for attaching GUI components
Container contentPane = getContentPane();

// enable explicit positioning of GUI components
 contentPane.setLayout( null );

texto1= new JLabel("Dado 1");
texto1.setBounds(30,30,50,15);
contentPane.add(texto1);

caja1= new JTextField();
caja1.setBounds(80,30,60,15);
caja1.setEditable(false);
contentPane.add(caja1);

texto2= new JLabel("Dado 2");
texto2.setBounds(160,30,50,15);
contentPane.add(texto2);

caja2= new JTextField();
caja2.setBounds(210,30,60,15);
caja2.setEditable(false);
contentPane.add(caja2);

texto3= new JLabel("Suma");
texto3.setBounds(290,30,50,15);
contentPane.add(texto3);

caja3= new JTextField();
caja3.setBounds(340,30,60,15);
caja3.setEditable(false);
contentPane.add(caja3);

texto4= new JLabel("Punto");
texto4.setBounds(420,30,50,15);
contentPane.add(texto4);

caja4= new JTextField();
caja4.setBounds(470,30,60,15);
caja4.setEditable(false);
contentPane.add(caja4);

botonjugar = new JButton("Tirar los dados");
botonjugar.setBounds(250,60,150,30 );       
contentPane.add(botonjugar);
botonjugar.addActionListener(

 new ActionListener() 
 {             
     public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent event )
     {
        botonjugar_presionado( event );
     }

 } 
 );

textoinfo = new JLabel("Lanzar los dados para iniciar el juego");
textoinfo.setBounds(30,170,400,30);
contentPane.add(textoinfo);

setTitle("Deber Tres Programacion");
setVisible(true);
setSize(600,400);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);                 
}

private void botonjugar_presionado( ActionEvent event)

{

if (chequear == true)
{       
 // puede contener CONTINUE, WON or LOST
    sumOfDice = rollDice(); // primera vez que se lanzan los dados

    System.out.println("Inicio");                       
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(sumOfDice));
    chequear = false;   
switch (sumOfDice)
{
    case SEVEN: // win with 7 on first roll
    case YO_LEVEN: // win with 11 on first roll
    System.out.println("it got here 7,11");
    gameStatus = "WON";
    case SNAKE_EYES: // lose with 2 on first roll
    case TREY: // lose with 3 on first roll
    case BOX_CARS: // lose with 12 on first roll
    gameStatus = "LOST";
    System.out.println("it got 2,3,12");
    case 4:  // did not win or lose, so remember point
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 10:
    gameStatus = "CONTINUE"; // game is not over
    System.out.println("it got here 4,5,6,8,9,10");
    myPoint = sumOfDice; // remember the point
    prueba = Integer.toString(myPoint);
    caja4.setText(prueba);
    textoinfo.setText("Lanzar los dados para continuar el juego");
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(myPoint));
    break;
}
}

//while game is not complete
if (gameStatus.equals("CONTINUE"))
    {
    sumOfDice = rollDice();  //roll dice again

    // determine game status
    if ( sumOfDice == myPoint ) // win by making point
        gameStatus = "WON";             
        else
    if ( sumOfDice == SEVEN ) // lose by rolling 7 before point
        gameStatus = "LOST";
    } // end while

    // display won or lost message
    if( gameStatus.equals("WON"))
    {
        textoinfo.setText("El jugador Gana.Lanzar los dados para iniciar otro     juego");//System.out.println( "Player wins" );
        caja4.setText("");
        chequear = true;
    }
    else if (gameStatus == "LOST")
    {
        textoinfo.setText("El jugador Pierde.Lanzar los dados para iniciar otro juego");//System.out.println( "Player loses" );
        caja4.setText("");
        chequear = true;
    }
 }  // end main

 public static int rollDice()
{
//pick random die values
int die1 = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt(6);// Primer dado tirado
int die2 = 1 + randomNumbers.nextInt(6);// segundo dado tirado

caja1.setText(Integer.toString(die1));
caja2.setText(Integer.toString(die2));

int sum = die1 + die2;

caja3.setText(Integer.toString(sum));

return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
//Create and set up the window.

new HelloWorld(); 

}  
}
```

Comment: I still see the same mistakes as in [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30852433/craps-java-programs-not-returning-correct-value-on-method-random-data), such as comparing strings with `==` instead of `equals()` and no `break` statements in the `switch`.

Comment: @Jesper sorry im working on two computers. I just edited it in here. But do you have any idea why is that happening. It is so weird and its so frustrating  I can't figure it out. Any ways thanks for helping out again.

Comment: It would be awesome if you put a little work into [slimming this down](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your problem is that a `System.out.println()` of the result of your method is doing funny stuff, then all you should be giving us is that method and a simple `main()` that demonstrates the problem. 211 lines of code is rather over the top for the problem you claim you're having, isn't it?

Comment: and effort into the formatting as well. Makes me not want to read any of it.

Comment: You have this `sumOfDice = rollDice();` twice in your code.
Once in this `if` statement `if (chequear == true)` and then inside this `if` statement `if (gameStatus.equals("CONTINUE"))`. Try doing it once outside both `if`s and then use the variable `sumOfDice` twice.

Comment: @BalkrishnaRawool I tried doing that and print twice using sumOfDice and it prints twice the same number. I dont know why it does it is inside the if statement. Thanks For the help

Comment: Ok, so first of all you are not using `break` statements inside your `switch`. Secondly, you are doing everything without any chances to pause or update the Ui, which means that if a point is rolled, you go straight on to seeing if the point is made before your text fields have a chance to be updated. In essence, you roll once, get a 3 and a 1, and then **immediately** roll again, get a 4 and a 3, and that second roll is all the user ever sees in the UI. It's not clear to me whether this is a bug or a feature, though.

Comment: @omachu23: If that helped I can put it as an answer and you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are calling `rollDice()` again in `if (gameStatus == "CONTINUE")`.
Actually to roll dice again user will again click on button and whole process will repeat. You don't need to call it again in there.

It will run fine by just removing `rollDice()` from there.

i.e.

```
//while game is not complete
if (gameStatus == "CONTINUE") {
    sumOfDice = rollDice();  //roll dice again  !!! remove this line !!!

    // determine game status
    if (sumOfDice == myPoint) // win by making point
    {
....
```

Modify this code to this

```
//while game is not complete
if (gameStatus == "CONTINUE") {
    // determine game status
    if (sumOfDice == myPoint) // win by making point
    {
....
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change all your if's in which you are comparing two strings like this:

```
if (gameStatus == "CONTINUE")
```

to this:

```
if (gameStatus.equals("CONTINUE"))
```

**You have to remember that, for comparing two `Strings`, you have to use `.equals()` function, not `==`.**

I expect it will be helpful for you!